# Selenium tests and network timeout issues

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, network-programming, timeout

I am using selenium to automate test cases, however so far the tests are flaky due to network issues (slowness etc..). this results in many failing test cases. Currently, rerunning failed test cases is taking considerable amount of time, making automation highly inefficient as opposed to manual testing.
Is there a way to make the testing more dynamic other than adding implicit and explicit timeouts.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So far my way of dealing with this is to write a helper function to wrap WebDriverWait, so that it's not quite as burdensome to use.

Here's an example using the WebDriver Python bindings:

```
# Import EC:
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Then define the helper:
def wait_for_clickability_then_click_element(self, by, locator, timeout=5):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
            by, locator)))
    if by == By.XPATH:
        self.driver.febx(locator).click()
    elif by == By.CSS_SELECTOR:
        self.driver.febc(locator).click()
```

An example invocation (which you might use in place of a normal click() call you run into timing issues) could look like:

```
wait_for_clickability_then_click_element(
    By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[name='submit']")
```